# Error: Could not find or load mail class? (Java)

Tags: java, class, email, load, program-entry-point

I'm fully aware that this topic has already been touched upon so many times already. Yet, having browsed through many of them couldn't solve my problem so here I am asking for your opinion.

```
    package email1;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

public class EmailAttachmentSender {

    public static void sendEmailWithAttachments(String host, String port,
            final String userName, final String password, String toAddress,
            String subject, String message, String[] attachFiles)
            throws AddressException, MessagingException {
        // sets SMTP server properties
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.user", userName);
        properties.put("mail.password", password);

        // creates a new session with an authenticator
        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
            public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);
            }
        };
        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);

        // creates a new e-mail message
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(userName));
        InternetAddress[] toAddresses = { new InternetAddress(toAddress) };
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddresses);
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());

        // creates message part
        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setContent(message, "text/html");

        // creates multi-part
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        // adds attachments
        if (attachFiles != null && attachFiles.length > 0) {
            for (String filePath : attachFiles) {
                MimeBodyPart attachPart = new MimeBodyPart();

                try {
                    attachPart.attachFile(filePath);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                multipart.addBodyPart(attachPart);
            }
        }

        // sets the multi-part as e-mail's content
        msg.setContent(multipart);

        // sends the e-mail
        Transport.send(msg);

    }

    /**
     * Test sending e-mail with attachments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // SMTP info
        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        String port = "587";
        String mailFrom = "abc@gmail.com";
        String password = "abc";

        // message info
        String mailTo = "def@gmail.com";
        String subject = "New email with attachments";
        String message = "I have some attachments for you.";

        // attachments
        String[] attachFiles = new String[1];
        attachFiles[0] = "D:\\Documents\\java\\2. 2014 VN Post Survey Seminar Presentation.pdf";
        //attachFiles[1] = "e:/Test/Music.mp3";
        //attachFiles[2] = "e:/Test/Video.mp4";

        try {
            sendEmailWithAttachments(host, port, mailFrom, password, mailTo,
                subject, message, attachFiles);
            System.out.println("Email sent.");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Could not send email.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Compiling went smoothly with `javac EmailAttachmentSender.java`.

But after that, when I run `java EmailAttachmentSender` the system printed out this line:

`Error: Could not find or load main class EmailAttachmentSender`

I've checked my CLASSPATH, also tried `java email1.EmailAttachmentSender` but to no avail.

Would you please help me check this.

Thank you very much for your help.

Zestos.

Comment: What compiler are you using? What is the name of the file?

Comment: `java email1.EmailAttachmentSender` should be the correct invocation (from the folder containing `email1` folder which contains `EmailAttachmentSender.class`). Could you share the error message for that?

Comment: ... along with your classpath, where you're running the code from etc. Basically the code within your class is entirely irrelevant - but your environment is *much* more important here.

Comment: @MatthewC: I'm using Notepad++ only. The name of the file is EmailAttachmentSender as mentioned above.
@GáborBakos: The only Error message I got was the message of `Could not find or load mail class ...`
@JonSkeet: Would you please elaborate on that? I'm new to this and all so details will really help. Thanks in advance.